# Understanding what happens after interpolation within ECG beat in python

Tags: python, signal-processing, interpolation, numpy-ndarray

I did an experiment with 8 different ecg beats from 8 increasing HR from 55 to 125. If I set up a stacked line plot in a way where the lowest HR beat is at the bottom, and as we go up, the HR increases. for the first iteration, I selected a fixed number of samples before and after the r peak and plotted them. no interpolation is done here as the length of each ecG beat is fixed.
Now for the second iteration, instead of taking fixed lengths, I take a proportion of some samples before and after the r peak based on the relative rr distance (which represents the r peak to r peak distance). so here, based on rr, the length of each occupied beat will be different. now I interpolate and create stacked line plots as in the first iteration.

what I observe is in the first iteration, if we draw a line from the lowest HR to the highest HR, the line slants towards R peak gradually from floor to top. however, in iteration 2, it goes the other way. why is this so? The two figures are posted here. One left is one before any interpolation or stretching. the second one is after. The slant of the line in both should be in the same direction, but it is not. I want to understand why this is happening.

[image]

Comment: maybe some programming error? hard to tell with complex description and literally no code